# Can I run an application that was built with Java 1.8 on a system that has JRE 1.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

In our public school computer environment, we are running "Version 6 Update 31" according to java.com. I have no control of when that will be upgraded.

My students want to create a Java application that uses version 8. Is there any way to create such an application that was built with Java version 8 (using Eclipse Luna) and yet runs on a Java version 6 Windows system?

Comment: You can set the Eclipse compiler level to 1.6 to get something that will run on JRE 6, but you won't be able to write programs that make use of features introduced in Java 7 or Java 8.

Comment: Java 1.7 has already reached end of life so the upgrade from java 1.6 to java 1.8 is well overdue.  You can run more than one jdk and jre on a single system, so can you get java1.8 installed on the relevant machines?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "uses version 8".  If you set the target as 6 and stay within the confines of the 6 language definition and framework, then yes, you can build applications on a Java 8 machine to run on a Java 6 machine.

However, if you mean "take advantage of Java 8 specific feature", then no.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you can run application compiled for java 1.6 on JRE 1.8, but in the opposite direction it will not work. You need to upgrade java, to the version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

In almost cases your cannot run any later version app with older version of same app. Unfortunately, same happens with `Java` versions.

Anyway, I gues you want a sollution more than a confirmation so, **if you can't install local `Java8` in your Students machines (you can use various JRE/JDK in same machine!!**). If the app is for educational purposes and to learn `Java8` i reccommend you use online simulator as [Compile and Execute for `Java8`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php) or [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) that I guess also has `Java8` compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile application by [Java Devlopment Kit version 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (setting language level: Java 8), you must run application in [Java Runtime Environment version 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse go to project menu and inside there you will find sub-menu properties click on it. This will bring up the properties pop-up window. Here in the left panel select Java Compiler. this will show the Java Compiler in the right panel. Now in the item "Compiler Compliance Level" Select '1.6' in the comboBox in the right and press OK.

There is another method While creating a new project in the "Create a Java Project Window" In the `JRE` section of the window, select the radio button "Use an execution environment JRE" and from the combo box to the right select the 'JavaSE1.6'. This will create a project which can be run in JRE 1.6.

This way you would be able to create application For JRE 1.6 from Java 8 but these steps above will restrict you from using the features that are available for JDK7 and JDK8.